# Proxy and reverseProxy for specific domain

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I am using Apache to serve my Golang website, `www.example.com`. All the incoming traffic is transferred to the port `8080`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/go/example.com/ui

  # Proxy (all traffic proxy to 8080)
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Besides, I also want to get the Apache server status by using `mod_status`.
I expect that I can get the status page by visiting `http://12.34.56.78/server-status`, where `12.34.56.78` is my server IP.

My `mod_status` conf file:

```
### /etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf
<ifmodule mod_status.c="">ExtendedStatus On
 <location server-status="">
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    #  Allow from .example.com
</location>
</ifmodule>
```

**SO, THE PROBLEM IS**

When I try to request `http://12.34.56.78/server-status`, Apache directed me to the port `8080`, which is not intended.

**WHAT I WANT**

I want ALL the traffic to `www.example.com` to be transferred to port `8080`, but not other traffics. What should I do?

```
I WANT:
http://12.34.56.78/server-status --> just serve normally
http://example.com/whatever --> to port:8080
http://example.com/server-status --> to port:8080 (okie, since it have the prefix example.com)
```

Comment: this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#serverpath could help